# Android studio gradle sync issues

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

below is code of build.gradle project level 
i ahvent opened it since few days before it was working now its give error as shown in image 
i have tried updating gradle version 
i have invalidate  cache and restart 
but nothing is working any help appriciated

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
    }
    jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
    google()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
  }

     allprojects {
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
        jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
         google()
       }
   }

 task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
  }
```

buidl.gradle 9app level

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxx'
            keyPassword 'xxx'
            storeFile file('xxxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.0.13"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        FREE {
            minSdkVersion 18
            applicationId 'XXXX'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            targetSdkVersion 28
            testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
            versionCode 13
            versionName '1.0.13'
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "versionCode"
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'de.codecrafters.tableview:tableview:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.f0ris.sweetalert:library:1.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.4.0'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960

Comment: i am not using kotlin anywhare in my project

Comment: No matter, try my dependencies to see your problem will be solved or not

Comment: but adding dependencies that is of no use to your project is it a better practice ? need to find other solution than adding dependencies which has nothing to do with your project or other dependencies 
and it was working well without any error and application is already publishes and updates are also given so there must be some thing with android studio that mess with this and every time adding unwanted dependencies is not a permanant solution

Comment: If with my dependencies your app works, you can simply delete unused lines after that

Comment: can you  paste build.grale app module please?

Comment: what i did is replace following line
 jcenter { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"}
    google()

with 
google()
 jcenter()

this worked for me