# I can't sync my kotlin gradle in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

After I started my Android project by selecting Kotlin as my language.The app gets an error when trying to sync with Kotlin gradle:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
```

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: No cached version of org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.71 available for offline mode.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you use `offline` mode? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22607661/no-cached-version-available-for-offline-mode.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960

Answer (score 0):

your android studio in offline mode so uncheck it

**File => Settings => Build, Execution, Deployment => Build Tools => Gradle => Offline Work**

After Gradle Sync Finished, **Please Restart Your Android Studio**.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switching off my grade offline toggle