# Need Help, I am a beginner on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I got the assignment to continue the Android Studio project, but when I will Release the APK there is an error like this.

```
../../build.gradle: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.

../../build.gradle: httpclient defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead), or repackaging the library using something like jar.
```

This in my dependencies at build.gradle

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

but i don't know where the problem..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960

Comment: `Need Help, I am a beginner on Android Studio` this doesn't help others understand your question at all - everyone here wants help :) please make your title more clear

Answer (score 0):

Add this in `build.gradle` locate in app module

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
    }
}
```

Hope it will work

Thankew! Happy coding!