# when I open my own existing project , this gradle build error is occuring

Tags: java, android, gradle

[image]

[image]

I tried all the possible ways. I cleaned the cache, invalidate cache and restarted, I delete project and resync the project, even deleted android studio and reinstalled it.

Comment: what is your app module gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3'` Also see here: [Android Studio can't find Kotlin dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960)

Comment: Try my answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61025926/android-studio-cant-find-kotlin-dependency/61025960#61025960

Comment: OK, with my dependencies at that answer, try invalidate caches/restart @Arafat

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. Go to your project folder and delete these files.

.gradle , yourProjectName.iml , .idea

Don't open your project, Go to File -> New -> Import Project